# Is it okay to define same ids in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I know that if we define different ids it is easy for us to find it in future. I found many answers but they're not what i'm looking for. I've a java function which is bit lengthy and will be used in many java activities. So it won't be possible for me to change ids for every java and xml activity. So is it okay to have same ids in different XML and JAVA files? Or could they make app crash in any way? IDs example :

**XML ACTIVITY ONE :**

```
<TextView  android:id="@+id/resultview"  />
```

**JAVA ACTIVITY ONE :**

```
printresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultview);
```

**XML ACTIVITY TWO :**

```
<TextView  android:id="@+id/resultview"  />
```

**JAVA ACTIVITY TWO :**

```
printresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultview);
```

As you can see above there are different XML and JAVA but ids are same.

Comment: "So is it okay to have same ids in different XML and JAVA files?" - yes. It is not a problem. Just don't place the same ids in the same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is okay to use same id in different in different XML files. The point to be considered here is that the activity inflates the particular layout and the findViewById method finds the view using the id in that particular layout that you inflated. Yes, this doesn't introduce bugs however it is a bad practice.

You can refactor the id's via android studio's refactor function. So if you change your id here android studio will search the usages of that particular id and change them for you. [image: (refer this image)]

1. Right click on the id you want to change.
2. Click on refactor
3. Click on rename
4. You will see the following dialog appear

[image: see this dialog]

5. Then you can change the way of refactor by changing the scope and other things at your comfort.

Answer (score 0):

You will not have problem because the components are in different XMLs. But it's better to put different names for them, you will be more comfortable yourself. For example:

```
<TextView  android:id="@+id/resultview1"  />
<TextView  android:id="@+id/resultview2"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem to give one id to many views but:

1. the views should be in different layout files
2. it is not a good practice

Answer (score -1):

There is no problem for duplicated IDs until they used in same file. But it is NOT a good practice.

Comment: `But it is NOT a good practice.` source ? why would i not give my toolbar the exact same ID in every layout if it does exactly the same thing ? surely that's based on preference